# Timeout errors with Beego on Digital Ocean server

Tags: linux, go, digital-ocean, beego

I want to set up Beego on an Ubuntu server (without Nginx), but I cannot visit the site and having connection out time errors.

Can anyone check my steps if there is any mistake?

Here are my steps:

1. I have used `bee pack` to pack my code.
2. Then, use FileZilla to upload the package.
3. After that, run `tar -xvf beego_project.tar.gz` to unpack.
4. Run the project with `nohup ./beego_project`

The code is running correctly on localhost but why can't on remote server?

Comment: Sorry I can't provide log information by now, the code is on a computer no power right-now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some critical steps.

Check out the deployment guide on beego:

https://beego.me/docs/deploy/

First, you have to change the mode to production. Second, copy the files over to the server. Next run the application. Finally, serve the running application with Apache or Nginx.

The two steps you're missing appear to be:

1. change app mode to production
2. serve the app with apache

Check the link for more details. **Important:** If you're trying to access the app from a different computer (production deployment) then you need to ensure apache is serving it correctly.

Comment: I did tried these methods. They are not the keys. Besides, before applying any of these methods, my server has beening working for a little while.

Comment: @ZizhengYang do you have apache installed, running, and have a config file for web routing? Are you trying to access your app from the same box or from your servers public IP from a different computer. If you're trying to access the app from a different computer (production deployment) then you need to ensure apache is serving it correctly.